# How to stop inner ng-repeat in a nested loop from updating when the array changes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays

So I have an array of events and each event has teams participating. these two object are related but neither is a property of the other.

What I want to do is loop through every event and display every team participating in it. I try to do this using nested ng-repeats. My problem is the inner ng-repeats only displays once the outer ng-repeat has finished executing. Meaning that what ever team participated in the last event processed will be displayed in every table.

In my controller I have an array of teams and I update that array every time I get a new event, and an array of every

here is my repeating table

```
<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-init="getTeams(event.eventId)">
    <div class="active title">Teams in {{event.eventName}} #{{event.eventId}}</div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr> 
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Sport</th>
                <th>Motto</th>
                <th>W-L-D</th>
                <th>Description</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="team in teams">
                <td>{{team.teamName}}</td>
                <td>{{team.teamSport}}</td>
                <td>{{team.teamMotto}}</td>
                <td>{{team.win}}- {{team.lose}} - {{team.draw}}</td>
                <td>{{team.teamDescription}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
  </div>
```

and here is my controller

```
(function(){
angular
    .module('foo')
    .controller('EventController', function ($scope, $location, EventService) { 

        $scope.events = [];
        $scope.targetEvent = {};
        $scope.teams = [];

        EventService.getEvents()
        .then(function(events){
            $scope.events = events;
        });

        $scope.getTeams = function(currEventId){
            EventService.getTeams(currEventId)
                .then(function(eventTeams) {
                $scope.teams = eventTeams;
            })
        }
})()
```

I have tried using track by but tracking it by the eventId or teamId does not seem to work. Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you have creating `teams` variable each time. It would be global and single for all events as per your current implementation. I don't think so you should be using `ng-init` here, rather perform that operation inside controller itself by looping over events.

```
EventService.getEvents().then(function(events){
    $scope.events = events;
    //loop over each event.
    events.forEach(function(event){
        EventService.getTeams(currEventId)
         .then(function(eventTeams) {
            //placed specific teams on event level
            event.teams = eventTeams; 
        })
    })
});
```

Then you just need to change the inner `ng-repeat` to below and remove `ng-init`

```
<tr ng-repeat="team in event.teams">
```